# How to run an Erlang MapReduce function on Riak?

Tags: erlang, mapreduce, riak

I'm new to Riak and new to Erlang. I have successfully created and run JS MapReduce jobs, now I'm trying to execute the following Reduce function:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130329021000/http://contrib.basho.com/delete_keys.html

What are the steps to execute this reduce function? Specifically,

- Where should I put the code?
- What should I type into `addReducePhase( )` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write something like:

```
MapReduceResult result = client.mapReduce("myBucket")
    .addLinkPhase("bucketX", "test", false)
    .addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson"), false)
    .addReducePhase(new NamedErlangFunction("riak_kv_mapreduce", "reduce_sort"), true)
.execute();
```

In this case the reduce phase call the function reduce_sort of erlang module riak_kv_mapreduce.
In your case you should call

```
.addReducePhase(new NamedErlangFunction("reduce_functions", "delete"), true)
```

(the true at the end is a flag that set if results have to be returned to client - last step - or not -intermediate step -)

The Erlang files should be compiled as .beam before use and added to 'add_paths' parameters in riak.config like

```
{add_paths, ["/home/vinz/riak/custom_modules/"]}
```

where /home/vinz/riak/custom_modules is the directory containing the compiled Erlang modules.

Refer to [Basho Java Client readme](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/blob/master/README.org) for further information.
I hope this helps!

Comment: The example above doesn't work. As stated here (http://wiki.basho.com/MapReduce.html#MapReduce-via-the-Erlang-API), I should set the "add_paths" setting in app.config. According to the doc, "add_paths" is a "list of paths to add to the Erlang code path. This setting is especially useful for allowing Riak to use external modules during MapReduce queries". Should I compile the erlang module first? How should I name the file? Thanks

Comment: Edited to refer to your questions. About how you should name your file, above the riak_kv_mapreduce module is contained in a file called 'riak_kv_mapreduce.erl' and compiled to 'riak_kv_mapreduce.beam'.